# How to name the Application for Java Mission Control

Tags: java, jmx, java-mission-control

I would like to define the name of my application so that I can see the name in Java Mission Control.

e.g.: Eclipse is named as "Eclipse (process id)".

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to, you could hack the plugin.xml file inside the JDK/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/com.jrockit.mc.browser_VERSION.jar, follow the examples of the existing naming rules. That's the only way, other than creating your own JMC plugin and defining the same extension in that.

(In the old JRockit Mission Control, you could do add names for your local applications in the Preferences, but we have rewritten the naming since, so you can't do it that easily anymore.)